# Kafka ProducerConfig log level

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j

I try to set log level for ProducerConfig to WARN with log4j.properties.

in jar - file I pass parameters: server, topic and path to the log4j.properties file. there is no priority change. could you tell me what the mistake is? log4j.properties file
my property file

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stderr

log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.stderr.Target=System.err
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer=WARN
```

jar run line example

```
java -jar /home/cb_kafka_l.jar 127.0.0.1:9092 topic_test -Dlog4j.configuration=/home/cl/log4j.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

-D flags go between java and jar, otherwise you're passing main method arguments

Answer (score 0):

The path to the properties file is the VM arguments but it is treated as command-line arguments to the main method of your java application because of the order they are mentioned in the java command.

Please change the order of the run command as below and it should work

java -Dlog4j.configuration=/home/cl/log4j.properties -jar /home/cb_kafka_l.jar 127.0.0.1:9092 topic_test

Comment: I changed it, but I see the same result